# How to create table in Transact-SQL from given script

Tags: t-sql

I'm beginner so how i can create table and execute then? Thanks for help

```html
  CREATE PROCEDURE `createAandB`()
  BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 6;
    WHILE v1 > 0 DO
      INSERT INTO A VALUES (v1, v1);
      SET v1 = v1 - 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET v1 = 1;
    WHILE v1 < 11 DO
      INSERT INTO B VALUES (v1, v1+2);
      SET v1 = v1 + 3;
    END WHILE;
  END
```

Comment: What is your question / use-case? What are you trying to achieve? Is this `[sql-server]`? Your tag `[tsql]` points in this direction, but the given code is not `T-SQL`... Please clarify!

Comment: tsql. I have to create same tables like these but I don't know how to get started? Thanks for your help . If you can write creating tables and insert data in tsql, I'll be very thankful for you. ..

Answer (score 0):

This is - to be honest - part of any beginner's tutorial...

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblA(ID INT IDENTITY
                  ,SomeNumber INT NOT NULL
                  ,SomeValue VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```

--insert with VALUES

```
INSERT INTO tblA(SomeNumber,SomeValue)
VALUES(100,'test with 100');

SELECT * FROM tblA;
```

--insert with SELECT

```
INSERT INTO tblA(SomeNumber,SomeValue)
SELECT 200,'test with 200';

SELECT * FROM tblA;
```

--insert a list
--I take sys.objects as a table, from where I can take some numbers and strings

```
INSERT INTO tblA(SomeNumber,SomeValue)
SELECT OBJECT_ID,[name] FROM sys.objects;

SELECT * FROM tblA;
GO
```

--Clean-Up

```
DROP TABLE tblA;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers, last question actually it is i posted for my client but I don't how I can execute it?

Comment: @samiullah To be honest: Read some beginner's tutorials, view some courses on Youtube, read StackOverflow examples, read the official documentation. Then come back with more specific issues. Happy Coding!